# MYSQL Left Join Not Showing All Rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

EDIT: I cleaned up the code to the following, still not working it's still only showing rows where **caregiver_review** contains a match (c.id = cr.practice_id) even though Im using LEFT JOIN

EDIT 2: I discovered that the problem is being caused by using aggregates in the SELECT clause such as ROUND & COUNT, if I remove ROUND & COUNT than all rows are successfully displayed in the view table. I need to use both and I still cannot figure out a solution, does anyone know why its changing the results when using ROUND & COUNT and how I can get correct this issue?

The query is from a view (read only) table called view_caregiver, These are the tables involved:
**caregiver**
**address**
**caregiver_review**

```
SELECT `c`.`id` AS `id`,`c`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,`c`.`address_id` AS `address_id`,`c`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,`c`.`last_name` AS `last_name`,`c`.`email` AS `email`,`c`.`phone` AS `phone`,`c`.`status_id` AS `status_id`,`c`.`summary` AS `summary`,`c`.`about` AS `about`,`c`.`business_name` AS `business_name`,`c`.`medical_experience` AS `medical_experience`,`c`.`traveling_distance` AS `traveling_distance`,`c`.`accepting_new_patients` AS `accepting_new_patients`,`a`.`address1` AS `address1`,`a`.`address2` AS `address2`,`a`.`city` AS `city`,`a`.`state_id` AS `address_state`,`a`.`latitude` AS `latitude`,`a`.`longitude` AS `longitude`, COUNT(DISTINCT `cr`.`id`) AS `rating_count`, ROUND((AVG((((`cr`.`rating_knowledge` + `cr`.`rating_personality`) + `cr`.`rating_office`) + `cr`.`rating_timeliness`)) / 2),0) AS `rating`
FROM caregiver AS c
LEFT JOIN address AS a ON (c.address_id = a.id)
LEFT JOIN caregiver_review AS cr ON (c.id = cr.practice_id)
```

This works but it only shows rows in which **caregiver_review** contains a **practice_id** match, I want it to show all rows from the **caregiver** table even if there is a not **caregiver_review** match. I know this can be accomplished with LEFT JOIN but I don't understand why it's not working!

Comment: besides all the columns you listed from the caregiver table, I'm not sure what other columns you have. If those are all of the columns you should user `SELECT c.*` to condense code further. That's just a tip, nothing to do with answering your question...I'm as stumped as you and mconlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is due to the lack of GROUP BY when using an aggregate function.  If you have no GROUP BY function, then you will not return all of the data.

You have two ways that this could be done. You can aggregate in a subquery and GROUP BY a single column:

```
SELECT `c`.`id` AS `id`,`c`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
  `c`.`address_id` AS `address_id`,`c`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
  `c`.`last_name` AS `last_name`,`c`.`email` AS `email`,
  `c`.`phone` AS `phone`,`c`.`status_id` AS `status_id`,
  `c`.`summary` AS `summary`,`c`.`about` AS `about`,
  `c`.`business_name` AS `business_name`,
  `c`.`medical_experience` AS `medical_experience`,
  `c`.`traveling_distance` AS `traveling_distance`,
  `c`.`accepting_new_patients` AS `accepting_new_patients`,
  `a`.`address1` AS `address1`,`a`.`address2` AS `address2`,
  `a`.`city` AS `city`,`a`.`state_id` AS `address_state`,
  `a`.`latitude` AS `latitude`,`a`.`longitude` AS `longitude`, 
  cr.`rating_count`, 
  cr.`rating`
FROM caregiver AS c
LEFT JOIN address AS a 
  ON (c.address_id = a.id)
LEFT JOIN
(
  select cr.practice_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `cr`.`id`) AS `rating_count`,
    ROUND((AVG((((`cr`.`rating_knowledge` + `cr`.`rating_personality`) + `cr`.`rating_office`) + `cr`.`rating_timeliness`)) / 2),0) AS `rating`
  from caregiver_review AS cr
  GROUP BY cr.practice_id
) cr
  ON (c.id = cr.practice_id)
```

Or you can aggregate on the original query and apply a GROUP BY to the columns in the SELECT list that are not aggregated:

```
SELECT `c`.`id` AS `id`,`c`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
  `c`.`address_id` AS `address_id`,`c`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
  `c`.`last_name` AS `last_name`,`c`.`email` AS `email`,
  `c`.`phone` AS `phone`,`c`.`status_id` AS `status_id`,
  `c`.`summary` AS `summary`,`c`.`about` AS `about`,
  `c`.`business_name` AS `business_name`,
  `c`.`medical_experience` AS `medical_experience`,
  `c`.`traveling_distance` AS `traveling_distance`,
  `c`.`accepting_new_patients` AS `accepting_new_patients`,
  `a`.`address1` AS `address1`,`a`.`address2` AS `address2`,
  `a`.`city` AS `city`,`a`.`state_id` AS `address_state`,
  `a`.`latitude` AS `latitude`,`a`.`longitude` AS `longitude`, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT `cr`.`id`) AS `rating_count`, 
  ROUND((AVG((((`cr`.`rating_knowledge` + `cr`.`rating_personality`) + `cr`.`rating_office`) + `cr`.`rating_timeliness`)) / 2),0) AS `rating`
FROM caregiver AS c
LEFT JOIN address AS a 
  ON (c.address_id = a.id)
LEFT JOIN caregiver_review AS cr
  ON (c.id = cr.practice_id)
GROUP BY `c`.`id`, `c`.`user_id`, `c`.`address_id`, `c`.`first_name`
  , `c`.`last_name`, `c`.`email`, `c`.`phone`, `c`.`status_id`
  , `c`.`summary`, `c`.`about`, `c`.`business_name`, `c`.`medical_experience`
  , `c`.`traveling_distance`, `c`.`accepting_new_patients`
  , `a`.`address1`, `a`.`address2`, `a`.`city`, `a`.`state_id`
  , `a`.`latitude`, `a`.`longitude`
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
select c.id, a.address_id, cr.practice_id
from caregiver as c
left join address as a on ( c.address_id = a.id )
left join caregiver_review as cr on ( c.id = cr.practice_id )
```

Comment: Still not working, although I used your sample to help clean up my existing code. I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's not showing all the rows that are LEFT JOIN.

Comment: are you sure you are not getting everything? Have you run counts on the table and the join to be sure?

Comment: Yes I ran counts on both the table and the join to confirm that it is not showing all rows.